# Alternative for using while loop to iterate Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an UPDATE statement that operates within a WHILE loop. In each iteration of the WHILE loop, calculate some count in the table and take an actions.

I have tried with Cross join but it can't works.

```
declare @rowId int    
declare @PrevRowId int
declare @Dataid int
declare @countexistIDs int
declare @countID int
Set @prevrowid=0
Set @rowId=0
Set @Dataid=0
SET @countexistIDs = 0    
SET @countID = 0

SELECT    
   isnull(t2.inqty,0) + isnull(t2.comqty,0) AS qty
   INTO #Temp       
   FROM tblitem t1,    
   tblin t2      
   WHERE t1.typeid = t2.typeid     
   AND t1.status IS NULL

SELECT top 1 @rowid = rowid, @Dataid = Dataid FROM #tempDataId     
ORDER BY rowid ASC

WHILE @PrevRowId <> @rowid
BEGIN
SET @prevRowId = @rowId 

SELECT @countID = COUNT(*) FROM tblitem     
   WHERE dataid = @dataid AND status IS NULL

SELECT @countexistIDs = COUNT(t2.typeid) FROM tblitem t2
INNER JOIN #Temp t3 ON t2.typeid = t3.typeid     
WHERE  t2.quantity <= t3.qty

IF @countexistPTIDs = @countID 
BEGIN
    UPDATE #tempDataId SET complete = 'yes' WHERE dataid = @Dataid

    UPDATE t2     
    SET invqty = t2.qty - t1.quantity    
    FROM tblitem t1, #Temp t2    
    WHERE t1.producttypeid = t2.producttypeid  
     AND t1.status IS NULL     
     AND t1.WareHouseID = t2.warehouseid   
     AND t1.dataid = @Dataid 
END

SELECT top 1 @rowid = rowid,@Dataid = dataid    
FROM #tempDataId WHERE rowid > @PrevRowId ORDER BY rowid ASC 

SET @countexistIDs = 0    
SET @countID = 0

END
```

I'm trying to do this using query instead of loop over each DataId.

Comment: Your SQL as posted is incomplete and thus has syntax errors with undeclared variables.  Please review the proper syntax for a while loop as well here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  MOST often a `WHILE` is best followed by a block with  `BEGIN END` not a SET statement.  Your code also uses a deprecated format that is missing semi-colons on the statements

Comment: Post everything, including the temp table you are trying to use as you might be able to join to that instead of a loop.

Comment: you can use `cursor` with `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD_ONLY`.. but avoid cursor when you can

Comment: I do not think this looks like it would require a cursor and you should be able to do this with a set based query.

Comment: I would also stay away from an associative join with `FROM tblitem t2,
       #Temp t3` as that probably makes your query harder to understand and maintain and also is a deprecated format.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, Okay, I will add #Temp table and use inner join instead of associative join.

Comment: Here is a tip, start by building a simple `select` query which obtains the records you want to update. Then add sub-queries and/or joins as required to allow you to calculate the values you wish to update. Then convert to an update statement.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged